# Get custom grails plugin version from within the plugin

Tags: grails, plugins

I have a Grails plugin that I've written that has its version set using set-version within our continuous integration environment.  While building, I'd like to programmatically output the version from within "eventCompileEnd" event hook.  So, for my Grails app I can just get the "app.version" metadata but plugin versions are set in the GrailsPlugin.groovy file in the root of the plugin.  Is there any way to access that value? Here's the version info I'm referring to:

```
class MyUtilityGrailsPlugin {
   // the plugin version
   def version = "4.6.8"

   // the version or versions of Grails the plugin is designed for
   def grailsVersion = "2.1 > *"

   ...etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use below `eventCompileEnd` event in `_Events.groovy` of the app to get the name and version of all the plugins used in the app from `GantBinding` which is by default available to the post compile event. You can filter your plugin info based on the `name`:

```
//scripts/_Events.groovy
eventCompileEnd = {msg->
    msg.supportedPluginInfos.each{println "${it.name} - ${it.version}"}
}
```

If you want to access the plugin info  from any where else (for example: BootStrap) using `applicationContext` would be the simplest approach. Something like below would be useful:

```
//Bootstrap.groovy
def grailsApplication

def init = { servletContext ->
    grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('pluginManager')
                                 .allPlugins.each{plugin->
        println "Plugin Info ${plugin.name} - ${plugin.version}"
    }
}
```

In your case, appCtx will not be available in post compile event, so you have to depend on `GantBinding`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that version information can be retrieved from within an event hook for that plugin by doing this:

```
pluginSettings.getPluginInfo(isPluginProject.getParent()).version;
```

pluginSettings is a bound variable in the current scope and isPluginProject actually returns a File object that represents the GrailsPlugin.groovy file.